# Object Scaling issue when zooming in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

So I'm having a strange issue when trying to implement the canvas zoom as described in the fabricjs tutorial (http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5)
Basically, zooming in and out works as I want, however, if I try to scale the object after I have zoomed in, it does a strange jump, see video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdrk4Uh9y8A&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=SimonOlsen
Anyone who has experienced something similar that have any suggestions to what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, so we can better help you with the issue.

Comment: You have two problems there: 1st: Need to be on the initial zoom (zoom == 1) and 2nd: Your canvas has shifted, you need to adjust to the initial as well. I just figure it out because I have the same problem, I will try to publish a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox object is set with `originX: 'center' and originY: 'center'`, there will be no jumping.

```
activeObject.set({ 'originX': 'center', 'originY': 'center' });
```

Comment: Both X and Y origin is set to 'center', so this is not what is causing the issue.

Comment: @SimonOlsen Can you please create a fiddle? So I can help you in this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you face is because when you zoom In everything has been shifted. So, mouse click will give you different position, the same thing happens when you zoom Out. And it will be more shifted when you zoom In on different points (since is using the mouse pointer as reference to where to zoom In) and then Zoom Out on different places.

A quick fix will be to store the first `canvas.viewportTransform`

```
    // This is on the mouse:wheel event
    initialVP = [...canvas.viewportTransform];
```

and then when you click on a clear button, you set that to the initial value:

```
// This is on click button event
canvas.setViewportTransform(initialVP);
```

[If you go to the first example](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#:%7E:text=things%20to%20discuss!-,Zoom%20and%20panning,-Let%27s%20see%20how), you only change the proportions of the coordinates.
[If you check the second example](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#:%7E:text=that%20is%20time%20for%20dragging.), you will have the additional problem that you can shift the canvas position. In this scenario, I think, that it will be more understandable what I'm trying to explain.

To find a good and best solution [read this article](https://roblouie.com/article/617/transforming-mouse-coordinates-to-canvas-coordinates/), get to the end. Because, the final solution is applying a matrix operation and it explain how to get to it.